# make android phone vibrate as soon power is turned on

Tags: android, vibration

I am building a device for the blind.

I want to re-purpose a low end android device for the task. In terms of hardware I need

- Single physical home button (to initiate interactions everything else is done via speech in & out
- Reasonable mic and speakers
- reasonable amount of cpu and memory
- rootable (we need to root to be able to do things like power down the device)
- 3G data

I have it working on a variety of devices but the best fit is the samsung pocket but it has one problem which I am unable to resolve.

When the user powers on the device it does not give any non visual feedback. Most devices vibrate when you power them on. The blind person needs to able determine that they have held the button long enough. The pocket doesnt provide any non visual feedback and what is worse if you hold it down for too long it powers down again.

Is it possible to change this behaviour. I am hoping it is in the boot rom. I am rooting the pocket using update.zip (home/vol_up/power ...) so I can do almost anything there but I have never created a custom boot rom.

I noticed that it comes pre-installed with odin if that makes it easier

I am a little out of my comfort zone so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need. Create a `BroadCastReceiver` like this snippet:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


                Intent it = new Intent(); 
                it.setAction("your.package.name.MyBroadcastReceiver");
                context.startService(it); //Start a service

}

}
```

And add this to your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.name.MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            </action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then create a service like this

```
public class YourService extends Service {



@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);



    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    long[] pattern = { 0, 300, 0 };
    v.vibrate(pattern, 0); // Use this to vibrate

    // rdlVibrator.cancel(); Use this to stop the vibration


}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

And last add this to your manifest file:

```
 <service
        android:name="your.package.name.YourService"
        android:process=":my_process" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="your.package.name.YourService" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

If you have any question just ask. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but I am looking for something much earlier in the boot sequence. Our app is run on startup and introduces itself but we need to have a way for the blind person to know they have pressed the on button long enough for the device to start booting.

Answer (score 0):

You can create BroadCast receiver that when phone turn on it is called and it's OnReceive method is called and you can write code of enabling device vibration.